# Use XPCOM to upload file/image on webpage

Tags: javascript, firefox, xpcom, imacros

I am using an example found here. [Mozilla developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/FileGuide/FileUpDown)

I am interested in this example.

```
function upload(postUrl, fieldName, filePath)
{
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append(fieldName, new File(filePath));

  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("POST", postUrl);
  req.onload = function(event) { alert(event.target.responseText); };
  req.send(formData);
}
```

But I can't understand what goes where on this example. filePath is understandable but postUrl , fieldName I can find. I am working on image uploading on the page that has Drag and Drop zone for image uploading. How can I use this function to upload the image on my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [**FormData documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) and [**XMLHttpRequest documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#open%28%29).

**`fieldName`**  *The name of the (form) field whose data is contained in value.*
**`postUrl`**  *The URL to which to send the request.*

You should have a server-side endpoint that responds to the upload request.
For example:

```js
upload('http://mysite.com/uploader.php', 'fileField', 'path/to/my/file.jpg');
```

Then if you are using PHP on the server-side; you can access that field value on the server-side like this:

```php
$my_files = $_FILES['fileField'];
```